Use React-Joyride with Shadcn modal or sheet
I am not able to use react-joyride with the shadcn sheet component.
As soon as the sheet is opened the tutorial automatically skips to the next step, as intended. The issue is, that I cannot click outside the sheet to keep the tutorial running.
When clicking outside of the sheet it just closes and the JoyRide component is unmounted.
I have tried to position the JoyRide component to appear above the sheet so that it would be clickable but that didn't work because Radix UI does it's best to prevent this.
Has anyone experienced this to and was able to find a solution?

